# How to run docker image on local server

Tags: django, docker

I am so new in Docker and i need to run a dokcerized django project which is already writen by another developer , this is Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /app/
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and dcoker-compose.yml :

```
services:
    event:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        
        env_file:
          - ./envs/development.env
        

        command:
            bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        
        depends_on:
          - event-database


    event-database:
        image: postgres:alpine

        env_file:
            - ./envs/development.db.env

networks:
    default:
        name: mizban
```

when i create an image with docker build --tag and then run it with docker run imageid it does not run  CMD part to run project on the 0.0.0.0:8000 port any suggestions?

Comment: What's the actual command you're running; are there any options to `docker run` besides the image ID?  Are you using the Compose setup you show at all or just running plain `docker` commands?  When you say "it doesn't run the `CMD`", what leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: Have you tried docker-compose up -d,
This command reads the compose file and will build the docker image. 
There is no need to do docker build and docker run.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes i use image ID with Docker run sorry for my broken English

Answer (score 0):

The `entrypoint` always takes precedence over `command`. Your file `Dockerfile.dev` contains both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. In this case `CMD` is used as the argument of `ENTRYPOINT`.

So if you only want to run `command` and not `entrypoint`, you need to override the `entrypoint` section with an empty string to your docker-compose.yml file.

Refer following example.

```yaml
services:
    event:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        
        env_file:
          - ./envs/development.env
        
        entrypoint: ""
        command:
            bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        ports: ...
```